# ST_LineLocatePoint with ST_3DDistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

I have a function who work great with 2D linestring... I try to do the same things with 3D linestring... but the result is nil :(

What's wrong and how can I fix it ?

```
def distance_to(poi2, way)
  distance_sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT
      ST_3DDistance(way.path::geometry, pta.lonlat::geometry) +
      ST_3DDistance(way.path::geometry, ptb.lonlat::geometry) +
      ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(
        way.path,
        least(ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry)),
        greatest(ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, pta.lonlat::geometry), ST_LineLocatePoint(way.path, ptb.lonlat::geometry)))::geography)  AS dst_line
     FROM ways way, pois pta, pois ptb
     WHERE way.id = #{way.id}
       AND pta.id = #{self.id}
       AND ptb.id = #{poi2.id}
  SQL
  Poi.find_by_sql(distance_sql).first.dst_line
end
```

Comment: Pls add information about your data. If we don't know how data looks like it is rather hard to find why it is not working.
I create some test data and function return result so probably one of your geom is null value if function return nil

Comment: The problem is that St_lineLocatePoint work only with 2D linestring

Comment: No, it is working with 3D also (for sure in PostGIS 2.3) check yourself


       select ST_LineLocatePoint(st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(0 0 0, 100 0 10)'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(1 1 1)') )

Comment: I'm in postgis 2.2 :
Returns a float between 0 and 1 representing the location of the closest point on LineString to the given Point, as a fraction of total 2d line length. :(

Comment: i've check on PostGis 2.2 and ST_LineLocatePoint works perfectly fine with 3D also. If your results return null it has to be a question of your data, not your SQL. Could you show example of your data?

Comment: way.path like like : #<RGeo::Geos::CAPILineStringImpl:0x3fd7545289f4 "LINESTRING  2.7596282958984375 44.52294742992487, 2.4825668334960938 44.6061127451739)">
pta or ptb lonlat like : #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fd75772eed0 "POINT (-8.5448445 42.8782132)">

Comment: Your example data are 2D so why do you try to use 3D then? Btw. it works for me on Postgres 9.5 with PostGis 2.2

Comment: Sorry is a mistake... it's my 2d datas but I have 3d datas

Comment: Is example query  from documentation retrun value for you
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html?

Comment: Unrelated - your result even if not null will be incorrect - you retrun distance between points and linestrings from geometry (so it will by in units of that geometry, and units of 4326 are degrees not meters) and retrun length of linestring from geography which will be in meters not in degrees.
So you will add "a(degrees) + b(degrees) +c(meters)= very strange result"

Comment: Thanks for your help, there work fine now. How can I order the result by distance ?

Comment: Just add "order by X" clause on the on the end of the query, where X is the name of the column or id of the column. 
So for example "order by dst_line" or "order by 1"